# Installing Remmina on Yocto Project

Tags: yocto, rdp

I have a YOCTO image running on ARM based board(ICM 3011). I want to install Remmina (rdp client) on the image. The problem is I dont have apt-get on the image , I dont have any package managers either. I have tried downloading the tar file from remmina.org but cannot install it as I dont have cmake or make or gcc on the yocto image.

I have tried to run binaries from this site (https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=remmina) but when i run the binary it gives error "EXEC format error".

Can anyone please show me how to install Remmina on yocto (on a arm based processor) with using apt-get or cmake or building the source as I dont have compilers for that either.

Comment: Yocto is not an operating system (it's more like a build system to create one). There may be a package manager on a Yocto-based OS, or there might not -- it depends on the decisions made by the people who built the OS image. Whatever the case, it's unlikely that the package feeds would have software like remmina available.
It's likely you will have to compile software like this yourself: Your OS vendor may have an SDK available for that. Alternatively (e.g. if you've built the Yocto image yourself), you can just write a recipe for remmina and then include the remmina package in your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remmina is Appication will work only on Distributions like Ubunutu, Fedora and custom distributions like wayland, chromium. If your project supports distributions (GUI), you can incorporate the application to your project.

Comment: The yocto project supports gtk3. I want a way to install remmina on yocto and armv7 based processor. Is there a tutorial to do that ?

Comment: I did look at it, but this is a recipe to add to Yocto . I want to install remmina without building the image.

Comment: @Adds Do you have a package manager installed in your image? maybe `smart`? maybe you can add a debian repo, or at least load the debs on your board an install them from local. http://labix.org/smart/user-guide/Command%20Line%20Interface#line-285